# Is increase in memory usage of my code possible without any memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

There is a C++ code which does some calculations in iterations of a loop. When I run my code for a couple of hours, no increase in memory usage is observable. But when I let it run over night, 50 MB increase in memory usage is observed by MS Performance Monitor tool (perfmon.exe) as shown below. Plots are only for my process not the entire system.

[image]

[Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/releases) cannot detect any memory leak inside the implemented loop. Is it possible that cause of increase in memory usage is something other than memory leak?

Comment: Yes; it's possible.  You could have lists or another data structure that are growing — you aren't deleting items so the list keeps growing.  Less likely is leaked memory where there are cycles of references between the items leaked, so the leak detector doesn't spot that there is a leak.

Comment: I see two possibilities: either VLD missed a memory leak (that can actually happen), or your code actually increase its memory usage (it doesn't take a memory leak for that, a memory leak happens when you can't refer to some memory anymore and thus can't release it, but you can also just retain more memory as the program runs).

Comment: Is this information specifically about your program or about the entire system?  If it is a system graph, other tasks or programs may be running that use more memory.

Comment: Let the application keep running.  If there's a memory leak (or an ever-expanding-data structure), you'll see the applications memory usage continue to grow indefinitely, until eventually either the app crashes or the entire computer does (more likely the former these days).  If there isn't a memory leak (or ever-growing data structure), then at some point the application's memory usage will stop growing.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Leak Detector could be fooled by memory usage patterns which look legitimate while in fact they are not.  For example, if you keep allocating some things and not only forgetting to free them, but also keeping pointers to them in a list, this looks like normal memory usage as far as any dumb tool can tell.

Also, 50MB are not such a huge amount of memory for a desktop application to worry about, and in any case your observations are too limited to be able to draw any conclusions. It could be that the memory manager of your C++ runtime considers these 50MB peanuts worth sacrificing for efficiency, so it may be choosing not to bother with merging adjacent free blocks to satisfy allocation requests when there is more fresh OS memory available.  In order to better theorize about what is going on you need to show us a more complete graph of the memory allocation of your application over time.  Is it a continuous straight slope?  Is it a slope which turned into a flat line at some point?  Does it have a sudden stair step somewhere?  Is it a slope which keeps rising even after you have completely ran out of physical memory and started paging?